# Dual space of $\mathcal{C}^n [a,b]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, dual-spaces, complete-spaces

I just started reading a few days ago about Banach algebras using the Kaniuth's book. In this, it is said that the space $\mathcal{C}^n [a,b]$ of $n$-times continuously differentiable functions is a Banach algebra with the norm
$$||f|| := \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} ||f^{(k)}||_\infty, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{C}^n [a,b].$$
So I have a question, what is the (topological) dual of this space? It is simple curiosity, maybe it is isomorphic to a known space, or to the direct sum of known spaces, I don't have idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to describe functionals on $C^n[a,b]$.

Consider the map
$$C^n[a,b]\ni f \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n \times C[a,b]$$

$$f \mapsto (f(a), f'(a), \ldots, f^{n-1}(a), f^{(n)})$$

Fact: the map above is a linear isomorphism  ( see Taylor formula with [integral remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).

So now you have to find the linear functionals of the space on the right. Using [Riesz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), we conclude that every linear functional on $C^n[a,b]$ is given by

$$f \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k f^{(k)}(a) + \int_{[0,1]} f^{(n)}(t) d \mu(t)$$
where $c=(c_0, \ldots c_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ is  Borel (signed) measure on $[0,1]$. $c$ and $\mu$ are uniquely determined.

Note: This seems a bit strange, since we could have chosen $b$ instead of $a$. And what about  the functional
$$f \mapsto \int_{[0,1]} f(t) d \nu(t)$$
Or  the functionals
$$f \mapsto \int_{[0,1]} f^{(k)}(t) d \nu_k(t)$$
for some $1 \le k \le n-1$. Where do they fit in?

That is a very pertinent question. I will respond with this: we have an [integration by parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Repeated_integration_by_parts) that magically takes care of them all, if applied rigorously.

Here is another way to describe functionals on $C^n[a,b]$. Take $n$  points $a_0$, $\ldots$, $a_{n-1}$ in $[a,b]$. Again, we have a linear isomorphism
$$f \mapsto (f(a_i), f^{(n)})$$
from $C^n[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}\times C[a,b]$, so we get a different description of linear functionals.

$bf{Added:}$ Another way to describe functionals.

Consider $\phi_0(\cdot)$, $\phi_1(\cdot)$, $\ldots$, $\phi_{n-1}(\cdot)$ in $C[a,b]$. The linear map

$$f \mapsto (f(a), f'(a), \ldots, f^{(n-1)}(a), f^n + \phi_{n-1} f^{(n-1)} + \cdots + \phi_0 f\,)$$
from $C^n[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n \times C[a,b]$ is linear, bijective (ODE theory) and continuous, so an isomorphism of Banach spaces.  Now, representing the evaluation functional
$$f \mapsto f(x)$$ using the RHS data involves some linear functionals, that "solves" the ODE.

Comment: Nice answer -- but *very one-dimensional*.

Comment: @Jochen: Thanks!  Yes, it is very one-dimensional.  We could embed $C^n[a,b]$ into $C[a,b]^{n+1}$, by $f\mapsto (f, f', \ldots, f^{(n)})$ and then pull back linear functionals from the RHS.  Or just $(f, f^{(n)})$. But we need to see which representations give the same functional.  The $d$ dim case, $n=2$,  for the closed ball is also interesting.  Now we can embed $f \mapsto (f_{|S}, \Delta f)$.  So any linear functional ( in particular evaluation at a point) comes from RHS.  Get  Green formulas.