# dual space of $C^1([a,b]^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

What is the dual space of $C^1([a,b]^2)$ equipped with $\|f\|_1= \|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \|_\infty + \|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \|_\infty  +\|f\|_\infty$ ?

Comment: Did you already do $C^1([0,1])$?

Comment: It is available here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318715/dual-space-of-mathcalcn-a-b?rq=1